# How to deploy a react App on Namecheap subdomain?

Tags: reactjs, subdomain, hosting, namecheap

I created a subdomain in my Namecheap account and I want to deploy a React application that I developed in that subdomain. I don't have a clear idea to do it.

Comment: I think you need to access the server via cpanel built in terminal or create an ssh key and access the server and upload the build folder to the sub domain directory. Wondering if you were able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, hosting providers give you the ability to enter the domain name to be used for your web app. Instead of entering a root domain like example.org, just provide your subdomain like subdomain.example.org.
Then, you will be asked for a proof that you own the domain (or subdomain) you just entered. Depending on your hosting provider, the domain verification is achieved in multiple ways, generally through dns host records.
For instance, you may be asked to enter a text value in your dns records. Your dns host records may be located in your domain name management dashboard. Check the official documentation for Namecheap as the location may vary based on your registrar.
After verifying your domain (subdomain) name ownership, your web app will be served under your chosen name normally in a matter of minutes.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question. The OP has likely gone via the steps of adding a sub-domain in Namecheap via the CPanel. The question of how to add a react app to it remains unanswered.